# Inserts/updates are extremely slow with Merge Replication in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I got hired into a new company and they had merge replication already in place. They have had issues with it to the point I have to evaluate whether to keep it or replace it. The main issue is it takes many hours (over 12 hours in some cases) to insert or update a record. Honestly that is just unacceptable.

As an example I am trying to insert one record into a table (`ComputerUsers`) that links a laptop to a user. You only have two columns (one is call `ComputerID` and one is called `UserID`). There is a `Computers` table that stores the `ComputerID`s and the `Computername`. There also is a `Users` table that stored the `UserID` and `username`.

All I am trying is insert one record into the `ComputerUsers` table. Last time I ran it it took over 13 hours. This table is published and it is part of the Dynamic Filter.

I have tried everything I have read online. I created two separate indexes for the `UserID` and `ComputerID` columns since they are both included in separate joins in the Filter. There is also a clustered primary key on the `Userid` and `ComputerID` columns since the combination of the two are unique (A computer can be assigned to two users or vica versa). I have also have tried rebuilding the indexes and even created some suggested indexes on the merge replication tables.

I am at my wit's end. What am I missing? I find it hard to believe this is normal for Replication because I doubt anyone would use it if it was. Thanks.

Comment: What service pack you are running 2008 SQL server ? What edition - standard, enterprise? - for pub, subscriber and distributor.

Comment: Also, try running sp_whoisactive when you are doing an insert - what wait types are associated, how many CPU, memory, etc.

Comment: Have you checked the overall performance of the server?  Is there blocking?  When was the last time statistics were updated?

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 Standard Edition. Do you applying service pack 3 would help? I also forgot to mention that I only do these inserts/updates on off hours because if I did it when people were in the database it would knock them out.

Comment: In all my years doing merge replication, it comes down to joins defined, and indexes.  That is where you need to start.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar sounding problem.  We replicated a table with millions of rows.  One of the subscribers would take up to 2 minutes to insert 100 new rows.

I solved the issue by adding an index to the rowguid column of the table it was inserting to.  I know this sounds like it should degrade performance but it looked like it was doing a full table scan before inserting, probably to make sure a duplicate row was not inserted.

Once I added this index replication was running smoothly again